# The art of exploiting people and taking advantage of them

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology

As one ages he/she will definitely encounter a lot of people who will do their best to make the most out of him/her.

Are there any books regarding this ??

Comment: Might be related: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8606/always-give-a-reason-why-how-to-describe-this-subject-area

Comment: One essential ingredient here would be to get at least a basic understanding of Psychopaths and how they often operate. There are countless books available on psychopathy. There are also books available on manipulation. One book, albeit dated, that I found interesting was [Methoden der Manipulation](http://de.wikimannia.org/images/Elias_Erdmann_-_Methoden_der_Manipulation.pdf), although I am not sure whether an English translation exists.

Answer (score 1):

From a hackers perspective I would recommend to check out a term called "social engineering". This is all about manipulating people in order to get sensitive information.

A great book about this is called [The Art of Human Hacking](https://g.co/kgs/sbIwNa)

Answer (score -1):

Look for persuasion methods. Read any book written for sales people. They use these methods a lot. Every time when I came across a sales person I bring my shield up because I know for a fact that most of them are well trained in these methods. For them it is a way of living